# Como consigo fazer um túnel tcp com o java?

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

A ideia é a seguinte:
Criar uma `classe` que fica de olho nos `eventos` do `socket client` e quando ele receber dados a `classe` redireciona para o cliente que esta conectado no `app.` como fazer isso em java?

Answer (score 0):

> Criar uma classe que fica de olho nos eventos do socket client

Crie uma classe que implemente `Runnable`, essa classe deve ter um `Scanner` criado apartir do `InputStream` do "socket client" que recebe informações do cliente em um loop "infinito", essas informações são tratadas e...

> quando ele receber dados a classe redireciona(redireciona o que?) para o cliente que esta conectado no app.

... envia os dados para o cliente usando o `PrintStream` apartir do `OutputStream` do "socket cliente".

Essa solução funciona se for trabalhar apenas com sockets. Mas eu nunca trabalhei com sockets e servlets ao mesmo tempo, mas deve ser a mesma lógica.

Esse [link](http://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-orientacao-objetos/apendice-sockets/#19-5-servidor) explica muito bem Como trabalhar com sockets